# Using C#, how can I replace similar words?

Tags: c#, string

Assuming these two strings:

```
string s1="control";
string s2="conrol"; (or "ocntrol", "onrtol", "lcontro" etc.)
```

How can I programatically find that s2 is similar with s1 and replace the s2 string with the s1 string?

Thanks.

Jeff

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could try to check the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) between your two words and if the distance is beyond a threshold, replace the word.

The hard part is defining the threshold, in your examples a threshold of 2 could work.

(*[Implementation of Levenshtein distance in C#](http://dotnetperls.com/levenshtein)*)

Comment: hmmm, it's interesting, and it's fuzzy :)

Comment: Very interesting. I never knew something like that existed. +1

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Levenshtein Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) which would give you a rank on how close the two words are. You need to decide at which rank you do the replace .

Answer (score 1):

I'll Suggest a simpler answer. Compare the length of the 2 strings & also compare the sum of ASCII values of the both strings.

Comment: -1: I like the way you try keep the solution as simple as possible, but this wouldn't even work with the examples that Jeff Norman gave. Levenshtein Distance is definitely the way to go here.

Comment: yeah you are right, but what if we calculate the percentage for the correct characters present in right places,i mean traversing each character of the right word & checking with the list of similar words every time a character is present in its correct position we add some value to percentage in the end if the percentage value is around 70-80 we'll say its a similar word.

Comment: By doing what you describe in the comment, you'll basically get a rough version of the Levenshtein algorithm. It's just not as flexible. What happens if you insert a character somewhere at the beginning of a string? The rest of the string will be marked as changed in your algorithm. You'd still have to account for that. Really, read up on Levenshtein to see what it does. It's fast, easy to implement, and it's widely tested and used for decades, all over the industry.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use matlab to run some tests on this. I would do the follow

CONTROL
1111111

OCNTROL
0011111

ONRCTOL
0000111

So I have all 1s for original word, than I have five 1s in a second case and three 1s in a third. You can say that 70% is acceptable and if 70% match than I will use this word. OCNTROL will get accepted, but ONRCTOL won't.

I say Matlab because you can easily load a lot of data into vectors and do vector comparissons.

Answer (score 0):

`Linq Method`: Try to store the chars in both the strings in two `List<chars>` or `List<String>` and compare (`SequenceEqual` or `Except`) the samller one with the bigger one.